# Overleaf Import .asy

Tags: overleaf

I want to be able to use this .asy package, and so far everytime I get a compilation error, the compiler completely freezes and I need to revert changes and make a new file. I just want to be able to use: https://math.berkeley.edu/~monks/images/olympiad.asy

I have searched far and wide, however I have not found a way to get it to work.

Comment: Have you asked the support of overleaf, if they also run Asymptote  ...

Answer (score 3):

*(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)*

Overleaf does run Asymptote, but `olympiad.asy` isn't distributed with the standard Asymptote installation, so you'll need to add the file to your project manually.

To do this, click on the Upload files button above the file list panel in your project, and then upload a local copy of `olympiad.asy` from your computer. You can also choose the "From External URL" option, and paste the URL  https://math.berkeley.edu/~monks/images/olympiad.asy.

[image]